# how can i attach an event to a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I had link and it automatically has a binding with jquery modal window which when i click, it opens the popup, i want to attach another event to it but it is just ignoring my code

i have this in my code just to see if i can execute the command or not, once it does, i want to call a coldfusion function to run

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer async>
                    $(document).on('click',".info",function() {
                        alert("hello");
                    });
                </script>
```

if i get an hello,

then i am going to do this

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer async>
                    $(document).on('click',".info",function() {
                        <cfoutput>#runmyfunction()#</cfoutput>
                    });
                </script>
```

Comment: ColdFusion is server side. The `#runmyfunction()#` needs to return a string. It will only run once when the page loads.

Comment: What you're trying to attempt here isn't going to work.  JavaScript/jquery is executed client side. To execute server side ColdFusion code, you will need to make an ajax call to execute it.  I'd suggest putting your `rummyFunction()` in a CFC as a remote function and then calling via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling another onClick, why not call the function within the existing onClick?

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer async>
   $(document).on('click',".info",function() {
      alert("hello");
     
      otherClickFunction();

   });

   function otherClickFunction() {
      <cfoutput>#runmyfunction()#</cfoutput>
   }
</script>
```